# The black and the white cat or cats?

Tags: difference

Which one of the following is correct?

> 1.The black and the white cat are my cats.
>
> 2.The black and the white cats are my cats.

I mean I have one black cat and one white cat.

Could you explain it to me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The black and the white cat are my cats

There is one black cat, and there is one white cat, and they are my cats.  (This is the one you want for your intended meaning.)

> The black and the white cats are my cats

There is at least one black cat and at least one white cat; those are my cats.  (There may be only one of each, but there are probably more.)

Basically, when you refer to individuals within a group, you use the singular noun form to refer to each individual, even if you then speak about the set of individuals as a group.  Nobody wonders how to pluralize "John" and "Mary" in the phrase "John and Mary are going to the store" even though the plural verb form "are" is used; so, if you can substitute a name (like "Tinker") for a descriptive noun phrase (like "the black cat"), then you need to use the singular noun form, even if the noun in question is part of a group ("the black cat and the white cat").

Answer (score 3):

Hellion's answer is substantially "correct", in that if OP has more than two cats in total, only #2 is valid. But it's important to note that we're not dealing with an *absolute, unbreakable grammatical rule* here.

Consider, for example, contexts where it's more strongly implicit that there are only two referents...

> 1: the largest and the smallest **number** *([7580 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20largest%20and%20the%20smallest%20number%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1))*
>    2: the largest and the smallest **numbers** *([2070 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20largest%20and%20the%20smallest%20number%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20largest%20and%20the%20smallest%20numbers%22&tbm=bks))*

...or for an even more convincing example, discard the second ***the*** (which is irrelevant here)...

> 3: the largest and smallest **number** *([6540 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20largest%20and%20the%20smallest%20number%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20largest%20and%20smallest%20number%22&tbm=bks))*
>    4: the largest and smallest **numbers** *([7550 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20largest%20and%20the%20smallest%20number%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20largest%20and%20smallest%20numbers%22&tbm=bks))*

Grammarians can pontificate over whether 2 and 4 are "grammatically valid", but personally I think it's nonsense to suggest that many native speakers can actually be "incorrect" in such usages.

---

Specifically in OP's case there's a lot of scope for ambiguity. You have to pay attention to the second ***the*** to even realise each cat is either *all black* or *all white* (not *piebald, black-**and**-white*). In my examples, there will be some cases where *several numbers* are ***among*** the largest/smallest, but I'm sure they'll be in the minority. And at least our real-world knowledge tells us no individual number is likely to be both the largest **and** the smallest.

In short, although OP's #1 wouldn't be valid if he has more than two cats, that doesn't imply #2 is inherently invalid if he has only one of each. It's more a matter of context and semantics than grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Either one is not understandable clearly to me at least. Speaking from non-native background, I think your meaning will be mostly clear if you write something like this:

> The black cat and the white cat are my cats.

Among several cats, to point out which are yours, you might also say:

> The black one and the white one are my cats.

Your first sentence might be misunderstood as:

> The black and <s>the</s> white cat is <s>are</s> my cat<s>s</s>.

It means that a cat whose color is black and white is your cat. People may simply substitute "is" in place of "are" and "cat" in place of "cats" subconsciously.

You second sentence ("The black and the white cats are my cats.") can be misunderstood as "The black cat and the cats *which are white* are my cats."

I think I could explain my point.

Comment: If, in order to misunderstand, you have to ignore and replace words, that's really not much chance of misunderstanding...

Comment: Well, I'm upvoting because it's sensible advice. There's no reason to agonise over the possible meanings/ambiguities of certain *possible* shortened forms when the sense can be unambiguously conveyed with an extra word or two. Native speakers only "delete" words when they think it's obvious what the missing words are. And that can vary hugely according to context. The best advice for someone wanting to *learn* is "only delete words that are obvious, and therefore easily replaced in the mind of the reader/hearer".

Comment: @Hellion, I understand your point. But please try to understand my point. I myself failed in understanding seeing them at first. Now, during speaking, if the OP is a non-native and talking with people like me who is also a non-native and understand ideal sentences only unlike natives who can understand colloquial English, I might assume the OP tried to mean something but made a mistake in speaking it and my mind would automatically correct the sentence to the nearest construction subconsciously.That's why I suggested them.